# HL7-Fhir : when posting a resource, is it allowed to reference to another resources by search criteria?

Tags: post, reference, hl7, hl7-fhir

Creating a new resource (patient) can be done by a POST to the server.

*Example 1]*
Create a new Patient 'a' which is linked to Organization with **id** = **1**) :

```
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "name": "a",
  "birthDate": "1974-12-25",
  "organization": {
    "reference": "Organization/1"
  }
}
```

However, I was wondering if it's also allowed to create a new Patient with a link to an Organization based on a search field?

*Example 2]*
Create a new Patient 'b' which is linked to an Organization with **name** = **orgname**.

```
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "name": "b",
  "birthDate": "1974-12-25",
  "organization": {
    "reference": "Organization?name=orgname"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference must point to a specific resource.  So what you've shown isn't allowed.  However, if you were to post a bundle, your Patient resource could point to an Organization resource within the Bundle and the Bundle could have a conditional create (using If-None-Exist) based on the absence of any resource that has a specified name.  But we haven't actually defined what happens to references in this circumstance.  (If you wouldn't mind, it'd be good to submit a change request on this.)

Comment: Is it allowed accordingthe Fhir spec to post a complete Bundle including other resources?

Comment: We're handling this by adding contained resources with only the fields that are known by the POSTer.  The server then converts these contained references into valid local references if the resource can be unambiguously resolved.  This gives us a (semi) portable, self-contained resource for exchange between systems that have pre-coordinated reference resources (e.g. Patient, Practitioner, Location) using a shared identifier.

Comment: And yes, posting a bundle is OK: http://hl7.org/fhir/2015Sep/http.html#transaction

Comment: If you send a contained resource, there's no expectation that the server will convert to stand-alone resources (and it's risky for a server to take that step, as containment is an assertion by the client that the resource cannot/should not exist independently of the container).  Remember, containment is not a packaging mechanism.  It's a technical solution for those situations where there isn't enough identifying information to safely resolve a resource or where updating the contained resource MUST change version, update timestamp, etc. on the containing resource.